# Using posix_spawnp gives "Error opening terminal:" error message

Tags: linux, posix, spawn

I'm trying to use `posix_spawnp(NULL, pgm, NULL, NULL, (char**) argv, NULL)` in a console application rather than fork and the rest of it.   The problem is no matter what I launch a message about "Error opening terminal:" is given.  For a GUI app, that is the exact message, for say `nano` you get `Error opening terminal: unknown.`, `mc` you get `The TERM environment variable is unset!`, but I forced in to the environment the TERM=xterm, it's almost as if the posix_spawnp isn't bringing over the parents environment, which I thought NULL was to do?

Answer (score 1):

`posix_spawnp` does not copy the parents environment if `envp` is NULL.   You must send a copy over using the `environ` variable which is defined `extern char **environ` so you end up with `posix_spawnp(NULL, pgm, NULL, NULL, (char**) argv, environ)`